# Removing special characters from a string

Tags: java

I have a string in my Java program which is read from database.

This may contain special characters in between as below:

> [image: Special Character]

I want to ignore all such special characters from the string such that the final string should only have alphanumeric characters (or if possible only characters belonging to particular encoding e.g. UTF-8, etc.).

That is `firm->s` will become firms in the output string.

How to delete all special characters except normal alphanumeric characters (or encoding specific) from a input String to output String?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StartXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="abcXYZ.xsd">
<MyTag>Gebrüder Leipzig→s</MyTag>
</StartXML>
```

And the error is:

```
Extra content at the end of the document Leipzig
```

Comment: actually → symbol is proper UTF-8 symbol

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I don't know.. but later in the processing, I am putting this string in a XML and then applying XMLLINT command for pretty printing. XMLLINT is failing on this special character giving parser error.. any solution for that ?

Comment: cannot say for sure, is it latest version? what arguments you use? is encoding indicated properly in xml/command line?

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I am using "xmllint --format myFile.xml" command.. and the xml starts with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"

Comment: maybe provide sample XML file which fails with error, hope we can solve it without replacing

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I have updated the question with XML and the error I am getting with XMLLINT.. thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39322/discussion-between-vicky-and-ilya-bursov)

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Can't.. its blocked! :( :(

Comment: XML file looks ok, but error is very strange
do you save XML as file? check its content via hex editor, what is at very begin and at very end, near → symbol - maybe some 0x00?

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Yes.. its Bytes: 0xFC 0x64 0x65 0x72

Comment: utf-8 file is better to start with [byte order mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374101(v=vs.85).aspx), so it should be 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF, at the end you should have 0x3e (`>`)

Comment: Those bytes that you've quoted look like they end "der".  So your hex editor thinks your file ends with those characters; which lines up with the "Extra content" error message.  Are you sure you haven't specified a byte count or something somewhere?

Comment: @DavidWallace: No.. I have not.. 0xFC 0x64 0x65 0x72 character is breaking the xmllint command.. the character appears before character s in Leipzigs.. On copying to microsoft word, it looks like a forward arrow as posted in the question..

Comment: This is not UTF-8!  0xFC 0x64 0x65 0x72 is "üder" in UTF-16 and also various ISO-8859 encodings but not in UTF-8.  Your input file does not have the encoding that you think it does.

Comment: Hear what David says! You don't have a problem with "non-alphanumeric characters" you have an encoding problem, your XML file is broken! It uses an encoding that's *different* from what it *claims* to use. Fix whatever **produces** those files. Working around such a bug is fragile at best.

Comment: @All: Changed the encoding... will post the output after a retry..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")
```

The `^` [is saying](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html): "Keep all chars that are not in the specified ranges inside the square brackets".

Comment: @MarounMaroun: later in the processing, I am putting this string in a XML and then applying XMLLINT command for pretty printing. XMLLINT is failing on this special character giving parser error.. any solution for that ?

Comment: @Vicky I don't understand.. It's failing on what? You mean after the replacement? The statement I suggested should remove all *non-numeric* and *non-characters* symbols.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The solution I asked in this question is a dirty one.. where in I am removing the actual issue... the actual issue is in XMLLINT which is failing when I am passing the special character as is in the xml generated from my java program.. please see my comments with IlyaBursov..

Comment: It it's failing on `→` symbol, after the replacement, you'll have no more `→`s... Make sure that you're using this **after** the replacement (I hope I'm understanding you..).

Comment: Why do you need the + in there?

Comment: @DavidWallace It means one or more symbol.

Comment: Yes, I know what it means.  Why do you think you need it?  `replaceAll` means replace all.

Answer (score 5):

Try the regex,

```
String result= yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
```

That gives you the `result` with only **Alpha Numeric**.

If you want only **Alphabets**

```
String resultWithAlphabetsOnly= yourString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
```

Comment: @Suresh Atta: I am using XMLLINT command in unix later on.. but that is failing on this character.. do you know a solution to handle such special characters with XMLLINT ?

Comment: @Vicky After execution of this line ,Just before executing the command then all the special characters will gets eliminate. You might still executing old string. Execute the `result` as command

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```
theString.replaceAll("\\W","");
```

This will remove everything except for letters, numbers and underscores.

Comment: Can you please see my comments below the question.. that explains the actual issue i am facing.. if you could please help..